# Why I'm not able to cast this interface?

Tags: c#, interface, casting

I add a reference of a WebServer to a UWP app. When I got the object fomr the schema, I want to cast on another object
This is the `WS_Utente` class I got from the `WSDL` schema (`ASMX`):

```
public partial class WS_Utente : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

    private WS_MetodoDiContatto mETODO_DI_CONTATTO_PREFERITOField;
    private int aREARISERVATAField;
    private string sEGRETOField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=0)]
    public string ID_UTENTE {
        get {
            return this.iD_UTENTEField;
        }
        set {
            this.iD_UTENTEField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("ID_UTENTE");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=1)]
    public string AZIENDA {
        get {
            return this.aZIENDAField;
        }
        set {
            this.aZIENDAField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("AZIENDA");
        }
    }

    public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
        System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
        if ((propertyChanged != null)) {
            propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

And I'm trying to cast to this object:

```
public interface Utente
{
    string ID_UTENTE { get; set; }
    string AZIENDA { get; set; }
}
```

But when I try:

```
public async Task<Utente> DoLogin(string Email, string Password)
{
    WS_Utente user = await service.LoginAsync(Email, Password);
    return (Utente)user;
}
```

It says its not able to cast from `WS_Utente` to `Utente` type.
Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add:

```
public partial class WS_Utente : Utente
{}
```

in a **separate file** to your existing `WS_Utente` file. *This is allowed since it is a partial class.*

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to inherit this interface:

```
public partial class WS_Utente : Utente, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
```

Second, why do you inherit object? All classes are inherited from object by default.

Third, all interfaces should start with "I", like "IUtente"

As [mjwills](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34092/mjwills) pointed, it's a good practice to implement this method separately from auto generated code.

Comment: That's what is auto-generated by `WSDL` code. I don't want to touch it...

Comment: Ok, if you don't want to touch it, just chang it to "public partial class WS_Utente : Utente ..."